# Can a Quintic Polynomial Be Solved?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, quintics

I am well aware of the fact that a general quintic polynomial cannot be solved in radicals. However, is there a known way to obtain a formula with other functions (e.g. infinitely nested radicals)?

Comment: You might take a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0955.pdf

Comment: Cf. [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406250/transcendental-formulas-for-roots-of-polynomials)

Comment: What would be the meaning of *infinitely nested radicals*? Sounds like the limit of some sequence? Are you working over the reals? You need something extra from the field for the concept of a limit to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the general quintic using infinitely nested radicals? Of course.

$$x^n=a+x$$

$$x = \sqrt[n]{a+x}$$

By an iterative process,

$$x =\sqrt[n]{a+\sqrt[n]{a+\sqrt[n]{a+\sqrt[n]{a+x\dots}}}}$$

Since the general quintic can be reduced to the one-parameter Bring-Jerrard form, then just substitute $n=5$ to the formula.

**P.S.** Surprisingly, the **two**-parameter form $x^n+x^2+ax+b = 0$ can be solved by infinitely nested radicals as well. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1179570/4781).

Comment: If you used $n$th roots of unity, while taking the $n$th root on both sides, would that get you all the $n$ roots of the polynomial?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: Ideally, it should by affixing the correct $n$th root of unity, but I haven't tried it yet.